# Steam is not working for Ubuntu

Tags: steam, chromebook

As root

```
`Failed to run gdebi-gtk '--non-interactive' '/home/cheesymelon/Downloads/steam_latest.deb'`

Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file.
```

That was what it said when I tried to install package, I don't know how to fix it, please help .

BTW I am using a chromebook with crouton

Comment: Try using "sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb" to install Steam from the deb archive,

Comment: @[Kevin Pham](http://askubuntu.com/users/589331/kevin-pham); Enter the command in terminal. Xterm is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal and

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```